# How to communicate with a c++ server hosted on amazon ec2?

Tags: c++, windows, networking, amazon-ec2

Background:

I made a small chatting application in C++ using winsock, just to try some network programming. I made a server and a client, and both communicated perfectly over My LAN but not over the internet. So, after some searching, I came across the concept of NAT hole punching, and got to know that it requires a public rendezvous server (i.e., a server not behind NAT).

Problem:

Then, after some more searching, I got to know of Amazon EC2, took their free trial pack, created an instance running Windows Server 2012 R2, and ran my server application there. Then, I ran the client on my machine and tried to connect to the server. The connection failed with a "Connection timeout" error.

I observed that my Amazon instance has been assigned two IP addresses, one public and one private, which means that the server is behind a NAT.

Questions:

Can I make the connection work, given that I know both the public and the private IP addresses (but not the port numbers which would be generated by NAT)?

Also, am I using the wrong service or doing something incorrectly?

Is there some alternative service which could give me a public rendezvous server and allow my C++ windows server to run? I know that many apps (such as WhatsApp) use an intermediate server for communication between two clients. I want to get such a server. What are my options?

Kindly help me. I have searched quite a lot and could not come across anything which would solve my problem.

Comment: Don't assume things like NATs just because of a public IP. It's most likely your security group that is preventing you from accessing it. Don't open it up too much when you do

Answer (score 1):

If your chat client is communicating over TCP/IP, you can use the public IP at Amazon to communicate with your server.

By default, security for your virtual server is locked down pretty tightly.  Use the Amazon toolset to open up the port(s) you communicate on.  For additional security, open them only to your IP address.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try this and come back if I have more questions.